# How to make particle system animate in different key frames

Tags: particles

I have a water spray which sprays particles at a given frame range. In-between there's a break where the spraying stops but after certain frames I want my spray object to spray particles again. How can I do this using the particle system? because currently I only have one frame start and end option. I want the emission to take place between multiple frame ranges.

Comment: Would it be practical for you to have the particles still emit, but turn transparent (invisible) for a certain period of time?

Comment: Would be better to have them stop at a certain frame range, but don't mind giving it a try to see how it looks on my animation. How can I go about making them transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I used a sphere as an instanced particle. In the field of the Value Node, enter `#frame` which will make the value correspond to the current frame number as you animate.

I made a simple "solid until frame 100 - transparent until frame 200" setup using *Math Nodes* set to *Greater Than* as a mix factor for the transparent mixes. If you are using EEVEE, remember to change the *Blend Mode* of the material to something other than *Opaque*, and also disable the shadows under *Shadow Mode* (as they will be visible when transparent otherwise).

[image: TransMix]

Comment: When I search for the "greater than" node, its not showing up with anything.

Comment: It's a Math Node set to Greater Than (click the drop menu that says "Add")